# Create accordion table with div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, accordion

```js
function insertObject() {


  var data = [{
      "nodeid": 1,
      "vendor": "0x0345",
      "product_id": "0x0201",
      "product_type": "0x0008",
      "home_id": "0xD087E344",
      "secure": "1",
    },
    {
      "nodeid": 2,
      "vendor": "0x0285",
      "product_id": "0x0777",
      "product_type": "0x0001",
      "home_id": "0xD087D213",
      "secure": "0",
    },
    {
      "nodeid": 3,
      "vendor": "0x1145",
      "product_id": "0x7899",
      "product_type": "0x0851",
      "home_id": "0xD034T13",
      "secure": "0",
    },
    {
      "nodeid": 4,
      "vendor": "0x8992",
      "product_id": "0x1236",
      "product_type": "0x8101",
      "home_id": "0xD0682F13",
      "secure": "1",
    }
  ];



  var tbl = document.getElementById('tableData');
  var tblBody = document.getElementById('tableBody');
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var value in data[i]) {
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      var cellText = document.createTextNode(data[i][value]);
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
}
```

```css
th {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #D5DDE5;
  background: #1b1e24;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #9ea7af;
  border-right: 1px solid #343a45;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  vertical-align: middle;
}

tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
  border-bottom-: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
  color: #666B85;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*grey row*/

tr:hover td {
  background: #4E5066;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #22262e;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background: #EBEBEB;
}

tr:nth-child(odd):hover td {
  background: #4E5066;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-right: 1px hidden #C1C3D1;
}

tr:hover a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

tr a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onLoad="insertObject();">
  <table id="tableData">
    <thead>
      <tr class="tableheader">
        <th>NODE ID</th>
        <th>VENDOR</th>
        <th>PRODUCT ID</th>
        <th>PRODUCT TYPE</th>
        <th>HOME ID</th>
        <th>SECURE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="tableBody">
    </tbody>

</body>

</html>
```

I have this `table`. The `tbody` will be populated dynamically with rows, generated by an `AJAX request` (each row represents a specific node):

```
<table id="tableData">
    <thead>
        <tr class="tableheader" >
            <th>NODE ID</th>
            <th>VENDOR</th>
            <th>PRODUCT ID</th>
            <th>PRODUCT TYPE</th>
            <th>HOME ID</th>
            <th>SECURE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want is an accordion type table, where I click on a row and opens this div which contains more info about the node. Here is the div (which is also populated with an AJAX request):

```
<div id="endDiv" style="display: none">
    <ol class="rounded-list">
        <li><label>ID: <input id="roomName"/></label></li>
        <li><label>LOC. NAME: <input id="loc"/></label></li>
        <li><label>EPID: <span id="epid"></span></label></li>
        <li><label>CLSLIST: <span id="clslist"></span></label></li>
        <li><label>TYPE: <span id="type"></span></label></li>
        <li><label>ZPLUS: <span id="zplus"></span></label></li>
        <button onclick="submitData();">Submit changes</button>
    </ol>
</div>
```

What I've tried so far is to give each `tr` a `class="breakrow"` but the problem I have is the div which appears on the left of the table. Here is the code:

```
$("tr.breakrow").click(function(test) {
  $(this).nextUntil('tr.breakrow').slideToggle(100);
  $("#endDiv").contents().appendTo(".breakrow");

  getEndpoints( $(test.currentTarget).find(".nodeid")[0].innerHTML);
}); //getEndpoints function populate the div with specific values
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not enough explanation detail for the problem to really understand what it is. A runnable demo would probably help also

Comment: @charlietfl i have edited the post and added a demo. So when i click on a row, I want the div to show up below the row, something like these: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you are looking for

A detailed view of your data on table row click

HTML

```
<table border="1">
  <tr class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery code

```
$('tr.header').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').css('display', function(i,v){
        return this.style.display === 'table-row' ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    });
});
```

CSS

```
tr {
    display: none;
}

tr.header {
    display: table-row;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pandiyancool/bLqzwfo4/)

Comment: yes, something like this. The difference is that if you look at my table I only have the headers, so the rest of the table has to be generatet dynamically(tr, td..), that's my problem. Somehow I need to find a way to implement this dynamically

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WKoRgX I've created this. Do you have any idea how to load the page but the div content to be hidden? Because now it's reverse working (instead to click in order to open, I have to click to close it)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using a table row with a single td and toggling it's display property rather than using a div. You have to set the colspan on that single td equal to the maximum number of columns to make the single column stretch to the full width of the table.

like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> node id </th>
        <td> vendor </th>
        <td> product id </th>
        <td> product type </th>
        <td> home id </th>
        <td> secure </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6"></td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

If you need it to be a div for style or other reasons you can place a div inside of that td and hide the borders of the column with css.